# How to remove part of string using R regex with boundary

Tags: r, regex

I have these 3 example strings:

```
x <- "AP-1(bZIP)/ThioMac-PU.1-ChIP-Seq(GSE21512)/Homer(0.989)More Information | Similar Motifs Found"
y <- "NeuroG2(bHLH)/Fibroblast-NeuroG2-ChIP-Seq(GSE75910)/Homer(0.828)More Information | Similar Motifs Found"
z <- "SPIB/MA0081.1/Jaspar(0.753)More Information | Similar Motifs Found"
```

What I want to do is to remove strings that comes after first word of the last `/` delimiter resulting in:

```
AP-1(bZIP)/ThioMac-PU.1-ChIP-Seq(GSE21512)/Homer
NeuroG2(bHLH)/Fibroblast-NeuroG2-ChIP-Seq(GSE75910)/Homer
SPIB/MA0081.1/Jaspar
```

I tried this but it doesn't give what I want:

```
> sub("\\(.*?\\)More Information | Similar Motifs Found","",x)
[1] "AP-1| Similar Motifs Found"
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a greedy pattern `(.*/\\w+).*` to match until the last `/word`, then extract the group with back reference:

```
v <- c("AP-1(bZIP)/ThioMac-PU.1-ChIP-Seq(GSE21512)/Homer(0.989)More Information | Similar Motifs Found", "NeuroG2(bHLH)/Fibroblast-NeuroG2-ChIP-Seq(GSE75910)/Homer(0.828)More Information | Similar Motifs Found", "SPIB/MA0081.1/Jaspar(0.753)More Information | Similar Motifs Found")

sub("(.*/\\w+).*", "\\1", v)
# [1] "AP-1(bZIP)/ThioMac-PU.1-ChIP-Seq(GSE21512)/Homer"          "NeuroG2(bHLH)/Fibroblast-NeuroG2-ChIP-Seq(GSE75910)/Homer"
# [3] "SPIB/MA0081.1/Jaspar"
```

In `(.*/\\w+).*`, the first `.*` is greedy and will match as many as possible, the stop condition is `/` + `a word`(matched by `\\w+`); the second `.*` matches the remaining part of the string.